# Type restriction for Volt Framework model throws error

Tags: voltrb

I would like to set type restrictions for a Volt Model like so

`class EventItemBlock < Volt::Model
  :name, String
  :items, Volt::ArrayModel
end`

When I save the file, Volt throws an error behind-the-scenes but does not crash. The relevant lines are the first seven (7), which state that the comma is a syntax error.

In the Volt Framework documentation, the comma is documented as proper syntax (http://docs.voltframework.com/en/docs/models.html). Removing the comma does not resolve errors--only removing the type restriction does.

`` [ERROR] #<SyntaxError: /home/jg/ModelTest/app/main/models/event_item_block.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
  :name, String
        ^
/home/jg/ModelTest/app/main/models/event_item_block.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
  :items, Volt::ArrayModel
         ^>
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:67:in `require'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in require_in_components'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:65:in `each'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:65:in `block in require_in_components'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:31:in `block in app_folders'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:30:in `each'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:30:in `app_folders'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/rack/component_paths.rb:61:in `require_in_components'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/volt/server_setup/app.rb:16:in `setup_paths'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/volt/app.rb:74:in `initialize'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/boot.rb:21:in `new'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/boot.rb:21:in `boot'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server.rb:44:in `boot_volt'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/forking_server.rb:73:in `start_child'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/forking_server.rb:229:in `block in reload'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/utils/read_write_lock.rb:65:in `with_write_lock'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/forking_server.rb:227:in `reload'
/home/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/volt-0.9.4/lib/volt/server/forking_server.rb:239:in `block (2 levels) in start_change_listener' ``

Answer (score 0):

Ok, two things going on here.  1) your syntax if wrong.  You need to do:

```
field :something, SomeClass
```

Second, you can't currently restrict to Volt::ArrayModel (yet, on the todo list)

Comment: I noticed the syntax about an hour after posting this--cleared a few things up. I will keep an eye out for updated restrictions, I know you've been working on the ArrayModels. Thanks!